# Using websockets (socket.io) for sails 0.10.x

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I am developing a node app on sails, my app needs to do regular exchange of data between server and client
The SailsCast video demonstrates the process for sails 0.9.x, and the mentioned files are not present in Sails 0.10.x
Also the sails doc says we should be using sails.socket instead of sails.io as the later will be deprecated in coming versions
Can any one help me in exchanging data between server and client through sockets. I have done it through node but with Sails MVC, i am not sure how to put the pieces together.

Any reference link or suggestion will be of great help

Thanks

Comment: Please read documentation http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets. There is everything described.

Comment: @icebreaker Thanks for the help, I know its too late to reply but I never came back to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble. You may want to check [SailsSocket doc](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/sails-socket).

If you are loading `sails.io.js` in your page and haven't changed the default 
`io.sails.autoConnect` to `false`, then a WebSocket should be created for you.

You can access it via `io.socket`

Create e.g. `assets/js/dependencies/app.io.js` with:

```
io.socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {
  console.debug("This is from the connect: ", io.socket);
  console.debug("WebSocket is connected:", io.socket.isConnected());
});
```

Make sure to load this file after `sails.io.js` (See `pipeline.js`).

Open you browser console and double check.

Also check [SailsSocket methods](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/sails-socket/methods)

Hope this help you get started

Comment: Though its a very old question now, thanks for the answer :)